# Programmatically convert and store unicode strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode

#### Context

I'd like to convert strings in javascript to its unicode representation so I can do funky things with it.

Some examples of what I mean:

I can write

```
eval('\u0076\u0061\u0072 \u006a \u003d \u0022\u0068\u0069\u0022');
// This is `var j = "hi"`.
// For clarity, I kept \u0020 as a space.
```

I can *also* write

```
eval('\u0076\u0061\u0072 \\u006a \u003d \u0022\\u0068\\u0069\u0022');
// Here I've escaped the backslash
// on the variable name and string
```

These are equivalent, and both result in `j == 'hi'`.

What's cool is that I can do the following:

```
var val = '\\u0068\\u0069';
var key = '\\u006a';
eval('\u0076\u0061\u0072 ' + key + ' \u003d \u0022' + val +  '\u0022');
```

This allows me to generate the values of `key` and `val` programmatically, using the following:

```
function uEncode(str) {
    var hex, i;
    var result = "";
    for (i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
        hex = str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
        result += "\\u" + ("000"+hex).slice(-4);
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

#### Question

What I would *like* to do is to be able to do the following:

```
eval(uEncode('var j = "hi"'));
```

This doesn't work because `uEncode` will escape the backslashes on the `var` keyword (`\u0076\u0061\u0072`) and the following characters: `=` (`\u003d`),   (`\u0020`), and `"` (`\u0022`).

If the the backslashes on the unicode for *any* javascript keyword or symbol is escaped, eval throws a syntax error.

Unfortunately, this isn't something that can be resolved with a simple

```
eval(unescape(uEncode('var j = "hi"')));
```

Is there *any* way to accomplish this?

Comment: Smells like fun to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval(JSON.parse('"'+uEncode('var j = "hi"')+'"'))
```